# Code Igniter CRUD app: thumbnail image doesn't upload. Receive database error because NULL

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Making a form that will accept a bunch of textual data and an image upload.

Keep getting this error when adding new item to both tables:

> Error Number: 1048
>
> Column 'id_path' cannot be null
>
> INSERT INTO `thumbnails` (`id_path`, `id_data_row`) VALUES (NULL, 17)
>
> Filename: C:\wamp\www\project\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 330

What I'm trying to do is add text data(stuff like title, text, price, etc.) into one table(**data**) and then upload an image and add its full upload path(as primary key in **thumbnails** table) and the id of the inserted text data row(to link it with the thumbnail in **thumbnails** table) into **thumbnails** table.

For some reason it keeps passing NULL as the full upload path to thumbnails table.

**crud.php**(the controller):

```
function add()
        {
            //Set validation properties
            $this->_set_fields();

            //Set common properties
            $data['title'] = 'Add new data row';
            $data['message'] = '';
            $data['action'] = site_url('crud/addDataRow');
            $data['link_back'] = anchor('crud/index', 'Back to list', array('class' => 'back'));

            //Load the view
            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('pages/crud_edit', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }

        function addDataRow()
        {
            //Set common properties
            $data['title'] = 'Add new data row';
            $data['action'] = site_url('crud/addDataRow');
            $data['link_back'] = anchor('crud/index/', 'Back to list', array('class' => 'back'));

            //Set validation properties
            $this->_set_fields();
            $this->_set_rules();

            //Run validation
            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
                $data['message'] = '';
            }
            else
            {
                //Save the data
                $full_file_path = null;
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size'] = '100';
                $config['max_width']  = '1024';
                $config['max_height']  = '768';
                $path_to_uploads='./uploads';
                $config['upload_path'] = $path_to_uploads;
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                //add this
                $this->upload->initialize($config);
                if (!$this->upload->do_upload()){
                    $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
                    echo "<script>alert($error);</script>";
                }else{
                    $upload_data=$this->upload->data();
                    $file_name=$upload_data['file_name'];
                    $full_file_path = $path_to_uploads.'/'.$file_name;
                }


                $data_row = array(
                    'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
                    'text' => $this->input->post('text'),
                    'price' => $this->input->post('price'),
                    'status' => $this->input->post('status'),
                    'type' => $this->input->post('type')
                );

                $id = $this->crud_model->save($data_row);

                $thumbnail_row = array(
                    'id_path' => $full_file_path,
                    'id_data_row' => $id
                );

                $this->crud_model->save_thumbnail($thumbnail_row);

                //Set form input name="id"
                $this->form_validation->id = $id;

                //Set user message
                $data['message'] = '<div class="success">New data row added!</div>';
            }

            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('pages/crud_edit', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
```

**crud_model.php**(the model):

```
//Add new data row
        function save($data)
        {

            $this->db->insert($this->tbl_data, $data);
            return $this->db->insert_id();
        }

        //Add the thumbnail upload path and id of the row in data table to link them
        function save_thumbnail($data)
        {
            $this->db->insert($this->tbl_thumbnails, $data);
            return $this->db->insert_id();
        }
```

**EDIT(html form code):**

**crud_edit.php**(html form code for **adding** a new item or **updating** an existing one):

```
<div id="contentColumn">
    <h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
    <?php echo $message; ?>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $action; ?>" multipart="multipart">
        <div class="data">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td width="30%">ID</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="id" disabled="disabled" class="text" value="<?php echo set_value('id'); ?>"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo set_value('id',$this->form_data->id); ?>"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">Title<span style="color:red;">*</span></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="title" class="text" value="<?php echo set_value('title',$this->form_data->title); ?>"/>
                        <?php echo form_error('title'); ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">Text<span style="color:red;">*</span></td>
                    <td>
                        <textarea name="text" class="text">
                            <?php echo set_value('text',$this->form_data->text); ?>
                        </textarea>
                        <?php echo form_error('text'); ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">Price<span style="color:red;">*</span></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="price" class="text" value="<?php echo set_value('price',$this->form_data->price); ?>"/>
                        <?php echo form_error('price'); ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">Thumbnail<span style="color:red;">*</span></td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo form_upload(array('name'=>'thumb', 'type'=>'file', 'accept'=>'image/*'))?>
                        <!--<input type="file" name="thumb" size="20" />-->
                        <?php echo form_error('thumb'); ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!--
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">Images<span style="color:red;">*</span></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="images" class="text" value="<?php echo set_value('images',$this->form_data->images); ?>"/>
                        <?php echo form_upload(array('name'=>'images', 'type'=>'file', 'multiple'=>'multiple', 'accept'=>'image/*'))?>
                        <?php echo form_error('images'); ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                -->
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">Status</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="status" class="text" value="<?php echo set_value('status',$this->form_data->status); ?>"/>
                        <?php echo form_error('status'); ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">Type<span style="color:red;">*</span></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="type" class="text" value="<?php echo set_value('type',$this->form_data->type); ?>"/>
                        <?php echo form_error('type'); ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Save" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
    <br />
    <?php echo $link_back; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: what you get var_dump($thumbnail_row) ??

Comment: `id_path` is **null**. id_data_row is `19`.

Comment: are you really getting value into $full_file_path before save_thumbnail function called ?

Comment: @GBD
Doesn't look like I am. I applied Rick's changes to my code and the database error is gone, **but** I still get *"You didn't select file to upload!"* when I click the submit button. Text data is added/inserted, but **thumbnails** table is still empty.

Comment: can you paste your html form code ?? or var_dump($_FILES) on start of method

Comment: @GBD
Alright. Check under the **EDIT** for html form code.
`var_dump($_FILES)` gives me *array of size 0(empty)*.

Comment: here is issue. remove multipart="multipart" and add this enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: @GBD
Applied the changes and still get the "You didn't select file to upload!", but now the `var_dump($_FILES)` outputs this `array (size=1)
  'thumb' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string 'tytry.png' (length=9)
      'type' => string 'image/png' (length=9)
      'tmp_name' => string 'C:\wamp\tmp\phpB81A.tmp' (length=23)
      'error' => int 0
      'size' => int 94355`

Comment: see my answer now.. try to change your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change php code as below

```
$image1=$this->input->post('thumb');
if (!$this->upload->do_upload($image1)){
```

Comment: Try this way $this->upload->do_upload('thumb')

Comment: *"The upload path does not appear to be valid."*

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!$this->upload->do_upload()){
                $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
                echo "<script>alert($error);</script>";
            }else{
                $upload_data=$this->upload->data();
                $file_name=$upload_data['file_name'];
                $full_file_path = $path_to_uploads.'/'.$file_name;
                $thumbnail_row = array(
                'id_path' => $full_file_path,
                'id_data_row' => $id
            );
                $this->crud_model->save_thumbnail($thumbnail_row);
            }
```

My guess is the upload is failing, since you're trying to do the save regardless of the upload failing the value for full_file_path is going to be empty. By the way save ONLY the file name and put the path in your display code. Saving the path makes it a huge headache to move those files to another location

Comment: The database error is gone, but I still receive the `echo "<script>alert($error);</script>";` error when I click Submit. It doesn't insert any new rows into **thumbnails** table, but it doesn add the text data into **data** table.

Comment: Then the issue is with the upload as I suggested. Rather than trying to echo out a pop up, in the error portion of the code put print_r($error); die; That will print out the error it's receiving to screen and stop the code from continuing to execute so you have time to read it. (it might just be print instead of print_r, I am not sure how it returns that data)

Comment: "You did not select a file to upload." That's what I get when I replace the error portion of the code with `print_r($error); die;`

Comment: Ahh I see what you're trying to do... and it's a nightmare, trust me I went through this, you have to do the thumbnail bit separately. It won't submit the upload as part of the form. Google Ajax image upload with iFrame and be prepared to pull your hair out for a couple of hours. Sorry =/

Comment: Any way around the "pulling my hair out"? I don't have to use Code Igniter at all.

Comment: Sorry had to go out. Honestly it's no easier without codeigniter. The only other option is to have it in a two stage form do either the data or the image upload then load the form for the other and pass it the data you need from the first one. For example do the image upload then pass the data from that in session variables to the data form and continue on. Doing it the way I suggested with the ajax is no different, you're still submitting them separately, but at least the page doesn't change.